# Docker and Podman: Segmentation faults on Windows 11

Tags: docker, podman

Recently, I get all sorts of weird segmentation faults when trying to build development containers on Windows 11 using both docker (2.43) and podman (1.4.0).

All the dockerfiles that fail now, have worked previously. However (and maybe coincidentally) since updating to the latest docker version I can't rebuild a single one of the containers. First I thought it would be a buggy update, but after deinstalling docker, reinstalling older versions, as well as installing podman and still receiving the same issues, I believe it's more a Windows issues. But since I did not touch the OS, I can't even imagine what could cause the problem.

Here is one for the dockerfiles that causes problems:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:1-3.11-bullseye

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y

RUN pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
RUN pip install jupyter
RUN pip install nltk
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install sentencepiece
RUN pip install accelerate
RUN pip install scikit-learn
RUN pip install matplotlib

COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The error (podman) I receive is

```
STEP 3/6: RUN pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
Collecting torch
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117/torch-2.0.1%2Bcu117-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl (1843.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.8/1.8 GB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Segmentation fault
Error:building at STEP "RUN pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117": while running runtime: exit status 139
```

Even if I remove the torch installation line, I just get segmentation faults at a different location.

I'm using Windows 11, Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621, on a recently acquired Dell XPS 17 9730.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.